# Style Atribute Text-Shadow giving an error invalid argument

Tags: css, google-apps-script

I am passing this css format

`"text-shadow": "5px 5px 0 red",`  
To the `.setStyleAttributes(_label)`  method for a text label and it returns the following error:

*Invalid argument: 5px 5px 0 red*

Is text-shadow not suported (yet) in gs or am I missing something?

Comment: There doesn't seem to be a list of whitelisted css , the doc only mention that *Since some CSS code may be malicious, attributes are whitelisted explicitly and therefore some CSS attributes may not be available*... There is a list of [html tags here](http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=175) and in a [release note](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/release_notes) but nothing about CSS or CSS version that are supported.

Comment: The text-shadow proporty actually does not seem to be suported (yet). I also tried it with the old fashioned james fereira applyCss() funtion but I always get the invalid argument. I´ll have to live without my shadow for the moment :-)

Comment: I raised an [enhancement request](http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=2242) if ever you're interested (I have no **shadow** of a doubt ;-)

Comment: Jacob Jan Tuinstra sent me the [link to the whitelist](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/ui_supportedStyles) text-shadow is indeed not present... too bad

Comment: Text-shadow is currently not suported would have been the answer, please keep to the point and avoid all the unnecessary.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a short answer that is not 100% conclusive but should be helpful. The CSS whitelisting in HtmlService is, in general, more permissive than UiApp largely because we can rely on the great work done in the Caja project to really think through the consequences of each attribute. If a CSS attribute works in HtmlService, and does not work in UiApp, file an enhancement request and it will likely get fixed (a few have been fixed recently this way). If the attribute does not work in HtmlService, it is almost certainly intentionally disabled rather than overlooked.

Answer (score 0):

The "text-shadow":"5px 5px 0 red" is used in combination with `setStyleAttribute`.

You're trying to enforce setStyleAttribute **s** with the above-mentioned.

Chained styling should be like this:

`setStyleAttributes({textShadow:"5px 5px 0 red", background:"red"})`

If you're using the James Ferreira technique, then start by using setStyleAttribute.

Ultimately the style you are using isn't supported: [Supported Style Attributes](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/ui_supportedStyles)

See reference:

- [setStyleAttributes](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_label#setStyleAttributes)
- [setStyleAttribute](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_label#setStyleAttribute)

Comment: The question wasn't about syntax (he showed only the relevant item in his code) but rather about this specific css parameter which indeed doesn't seem to be supported... have you been successful with the code you provide ? btw `setStyleAttribute` needs comma separated items, not `:`

Comment: @Sergeinsas: have you noticed the S at the end of setStyleAttributes?

Comment: @JacobJanTuinstra it does not seem to work like that neither, do you have a working example?

Comment: I just gave the proper syntax, see references. If you use the James Ferreira technique for styling, I would use the setStyleAttribute. I don't know whether text-shadow is supported. @Sergeinsas as Top Contributor can figure that out.

Comment: @JacobJanTuinstra : that exactly the point, there is a 's' in the original question, that's why your first comment "That's the syntax for setStyleAttribute" isn't right... but that's not very important, don't care.

Comment: ;-) unfortunately, top contributors don't have access to all information, only a Google engineer could answer accurately on this point.

Comment: @JacobJanTuinstra please put a working example. Your syntax gives the same error. Did you try the code?